# Unable to operate against JSON file in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, json.net

I have library application when there is possibility to register as new user, add some books, borrow them and deposit.
I have problem with JSON file, because when I take the data from it, I can't operate on this data using foreach loop. This is weird because, when there is no database.json file, and application creates it for the first time, every operation work very well. So error occurs only went I have database.json file for example when I want to run this application again.
When I remove database.json file, application start working fine again.
Under I put some parts of my code:

```
namespace LibraryManagementSystem
{
    public class Library
    {
        public Dictionary<string, object> database;

        public Library()
        {
            database = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {   
                { "books", new List<Book>() },
                { "users", new List<User>() { new User { Login = "admin", Password = "admin" } } },
                { "registry", new List<Registry>() }
            };
            Setup();
        }

        private void Setup()
        {
            string cwd = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string databasePath = Path.Combine(cwd, "database.json");
            if (File.Exists(databasePath))
            {
                string json = File.ReadAllText(databasePath);
                database = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
                Console.WriteLine("Library successfully loaded!");
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(database));
            }
            else if (!File.Exists(databasePath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I can't find database.json file from last session...");
                Console.WriteLine("No problem :) I will create new one!");
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(database);
                File.WriteAllText(databasePath, json);
                Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(database));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Psst! I have hint for you :) there is list of avaliable users, please don't waste it!");
            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(database["users"]));
        }
```

Issue occurs only in line like that one:
`foreach (User user in (List<User>)database["users"])`
and only when I re-run application or I have created Json file before.
Here is json how it looks in database.json:

```
{
    "books":[],
    "users":[{"Login":"admin","Password":"admin"}],
    "registry":[]
}
```

(Application created it when I run her first time)

I try some JObject, JArray... I think everything what I found in google. Even I use chat like get and Bard and even they can't help me and told that's code looks fine.
The error message what's I get:
nable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Well yes, if you deserialize as `Dictionary<string, object>` then how would you expect a cast of one of those objects to `List<User>` to work? It's not clear why you've defined `database` as a `Dictionary<string, object>` instead of a `Dictionary<string, List<User>>`.

Comment: Why do you expect `database["users"])` to be castable to `List<User>`?

Comment: _Maybe_ consider ditching JSON Files in the first place and use a _real_ DB instead. I think you could get started with for example LiteDB pretty quickly with very little changes to your existing code. _And_ have it actually work.

Comment: And for the record: I saw you are persisting clear-text passwords in your "database" **which is one of the biggest no-nos** there are, but I won't mention it.

Comment: That will be changed, but for now biggest problem is to can read and use data from database.json after re-open app
Here is link for full application code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XNM1EC

Answer (score 2):

On serializing the 3 dictionary entries, the serializer will detect their properties (using Reflection) and output them properly.

But when deserializing it can't do that because the *Type* it needs to fill is `List<object>` inside the Dictionary, and `object` has no properties.

The best thing to do here is to get rid of the Dictionary and use a class with actual properties, like this:

```cs
public class MyDatabase
{
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    public List<Registry> Registry { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
var database = new MyDatabase
{
    Books = new List<Book>(),
    Users = new List<User>() { new User { Login = "admin", Password = "admin" } },
    Registry = new List<Registry>()
};

// Save data:
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(database);

// Load data:
var newDb = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDatabase>(json);
Console.WriteLine("Login from deserialized database: " + newDb.Users[0].Login);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/p434ye

Comment: Oh nice @Peter B, that's works almost perfect :D
Now like you said, I created database.json file then, when I close the program, and re-open it, still I can login as a admin (It's good, before your changes, login after re-opened application I got error)
But what's about method where I save changes in file database.json after adding some books, or when new user just registered?

Comment: You can implement a Save() method and call it whenever you want, e.g. after data has been added or changed, or "on demand" when a `Save` button is pressed.

Comment: Also be aware that this answer is _so_ close to using a single-file Document DB, that it _might_ be worthwhile to you to go that little extra step. Except if you _need_ a human readable file.

Comment: oh sorry, Idk why but still I got this error message:
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LibraryManagementSystem.User]'.

Here is full application code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XNM1EC

Comment: Your Fiddle will work once you add `Newtonsoft.Json` through the `NuGet Packages:` box. I tried it and got no errors of any kind.

Comment: Sorry, I added it. Here is link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/lAXNaq
Here you don't check behaviors after created file, and re-opened application but you can check structure etc.

Comment: Your `public class Library` still uses a Dictionary, it is not using the class that I provided. You must get rid of the Dictionary and use the class instead.

Comment: Ok, but how I can use it after this? What I understand, I should remove database = new Dictionary<string, object> what is in Library class (above Setup() ) and this line: public Dictionary<string, object> database
Is that correct? If yes, how can I iterate in new structure if newDb is just local variable?

Comment: Sorry I just start learning C# and not everything is clear for me in this language. (I start writing it week ago)

Comment: In my demo, the newDb is a local because that is what is enough to make the demo work. In your code you should not use newDb; instead, do `database = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDatabase>(json)`.

Comment: I resolve this problem. You hint was awesome! Thank you @PeterB 
In Library class I has to change to: public Mydatabase database;